# Iptables "if not" condition?

Tags: iptables

I am trying to create a rule for iptables which logically does the following:

```
IF [destination != 192.168.0.1]  
    forward port 80 requests to port 3128  
else  
    carry on like this never happened
```

How can it be done?

Comment: end solution `-A PREROUTING -i eth0 -d ! 192.168.0.1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 3128` got me to my goal

Answer (score 4):

You can negate any iptables condition with a `!`. Of course, if you are using `bash`, you need to use a `\` as well to prevent some dirty syntax error given by the shell to you.

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING \! -s 192.168.0.1 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to your_outer_ip:3128
```

Comment: ok this should be what I need, I shall try this though just to note its the same IP just when a local server request is made the caching server interferes so I am trying to by pass the local address this way .

Comment: Your `!` is misplaced; that is the old syntax. This will throw a deprecation warning. The current syntax is, e.g. `! -s 192.168.0.1`

Comment: @MichaelHampton Thank you - I corrected - so goes it for old boys :-)

Comment: this is what I used to meet my needs and it worked perfectly so thank you! **-A PREROUTING -i eth0 -d ! 192.168.0.1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 3128**